# Hot to detect collision between a triangle and convexhull in Bullet library

Tags: collision-detection, bullet

I am trying to detect a collision between a triangle and a convexHull created from some rigid pints.

I have created the rigid object using btConvexHullShape. Can anyone help how to proceed with the collision test?

Answer (score 1):

Have you followed [this](http://bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/Hello_World) Hello World bullet physics tutorial? It has pretty much everything you need in it.